flutter and Android SDK launching app problem
When I am using my Galaxy Note 5 the android SDK comes a problem you should change your SDK version, Now the question is Which SDK version is best for all android phone in android studio for flutter apps?

Your Samsung Galaxy Note 5 probably have Android 7.0 Nougat, whose SDK version is 24.
Here are my SDK & Gradle configurations. (It complies with the latest Google Play Store policies).
build.gradle:
minSdkVersion 24
targetSdk 35
compileSdk 35

settings.gradle:
id "com.android.application" version "8.5.0" apply false
id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.1' apply false
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.23" apply false

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.7-all.zip


you can change the sdk version to 20 or 21 and it should work as it worked for me

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
